# tell python to "wait" to get full response after getting "Processing" from API

Tags: python, oracle, api, python-requests

I am submitting a `GET` request to the Oracle Textura API:

```
r = requests.request(method='GET', url=query_url, headers=header)
```

I know that the URL and headers are correct because they work for other smaller requests that I make before this one. Then when I investigate the output:

```
r.json()
```

all that `GET` returned is:

```
{'data': {'STATUS': 'Processing'}}
```

When I investigate the `r.status_code`, it shows `200` (even though I expected 102, which corresponds with the "Processing" message).

For context, when I submit the exact same query in Postman, I get the expected JSON full data output.

When I investigated the docs on Oracle Textura's site (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E97085_01/TPMhelp/en/North_America/helpmain.htm?toc.htm?10313083.htm), it says:
"The JSON query will be processed in the backend until it is completed, this will return Processing as the result. Once the processing is completed it will return the result set."

So is there a way that I can tell python to wait and not return the result until processing is complete? I've tried playing with `sleep()` but to no avail.

Comment: Continually poll the result endpoint until it returns data?

Comment: you can loop and do the request until the result is different, and wait like X seconds between each request

Comment: thanks all! repeating the request worked.

Comment: Yeah.  The documentation is really bad.  That page should answer your question and  tell you the best way to proceed when you get "processing".  You might even want to file a bug against the documentation.  But for now, I think you have to go with @azro's solution